# Is the expression (_, 'b') in Normal Form? in Weak Head Normal Form?

Tags: haskell

Working through an exercise in a haskell programming book, I am not sure of the answer and want to check my understanding.

The expression is: `(_, 'b')`.

Is this in Normal Form, in Weak Head Normal Form, or neither?

---

Here is a screenshot of the problem (#7) as listed in the book.

[image]

Comment: `_` isn't a valid Haskell expression. If `(_, 'b')` is what you get back with `:sprint` in GHCi, then that would be WNHF, since you know the expression as a whole is a tuple, but not everything in the expression is evaluated.

Comment: Was this really the question in the book, or were they asking about `(⊥,'b')`, maybe written `(_|_,'b')`?

Comment: @K.A.Buhr question has been edited to include screenshot of the problem as listed in the book.

Comment: I assume _ is meant to stand for a placeholder for something that hasn't been evaluated yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the author has made a bad decision to use a `_` character in these questions.  As @Alec notes, the string of code `(_,'b')` is not a valid Haskell expression (because `_` is a reserved identifier that can only appear in a pattern), so asking if `(_,'b')` is in normal form (NF) or weak head normal form (WHNF) is a bit like asking if an elephant is in NF or WHNF.  It doesn't really make sense.

If the question had instead asked about `(x, 'b')`, that would have been a better question.  This is a valid Haskell expression.  We can tell it's in WHNF because its "head" (the outermost part of the expression) is a data constructor.  In this case, it's the tuple constructor `(,)` which has a special syntax, so that makes it a little less obvious than usual, but note that `(x, 'b')` can be rewritten `(,) x 'b'` which makes it clear that the "head" is the data constructor `(,)`.   It can't be in NF, though, because `x` isn't fully evaluated (i.e., hasn't been replaced with its value, which is presumably given elsewhere).

In contrast, `(1, 'b')` would be in both WHNF (because it's head is the data constructor `(,)`) *and* in NF because that data constructor is fully applied to arguments and each of those arguments have been fully evaluated.

Now, I think that what the author *intended* was for `_` to stand for some unspecified, unevaluated part of an otherwise valid expression, so he or she intended you to reason that `(_, 'b')` is in WHNF (because the head is the data constructor `(,)`) but not in NF (because there's an unevaluated portion `_` floating around).  So, the "right" answer is "WHNF only".

Does that help?

Comment: A lot of tools (mostly debuggers) list unevaluated "holes" as _. I do agree that it should have been defined before, though.

Comment: You can write holes yourself as `_`,  and even run the code with `-fdefer-typed-holes` (in which case they behave like undefined). The author probably could have explained better how they wanted readers to treat the `_` in those exercises (I guess if we're considering them typed holes then they can't be in normal form because evaluating them blows up?), but it's not really true that `(_,'b')` isn't a valid expression.